# VK API users.get, не возвращает данные

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Вместо ответа возвращается NULL (var_dump);

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] === 'GetMembersData') {
    $users_array = array();
    // Узнаем количество уникальных пользователей
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $total = $row[0]; // всего записей
    echo $total . '<br />';
    // Вычисляем количество итераций обработки по 1000 юзеров за одну итерацию
    $ttl = intval($total / 1000);
    if (($total % 1000) > 0) {
        $ttl = $ttl + 1;
    }
    // Выбираем нужные данные из MySQL
    for ($i = 0; $i < $ttl; $i++) {
        $sqlzstr = "SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT " . $i*1000 . ", 1000";
        echo $sqlzstr . '<br />';  // 
        $sqlz = mysql_query($sqlzstr,$db)
                or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
        // Генерируем строку с пользователями, выбранными из MySQL
        $count = 0;
        while ($rowz = mysql_fetch_array($sqlz, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $users_str = $users_str . $rowz['vkid'] . ',';
            array_push($users_array, $rowz['vkid']);
            $count = $count + 1;
            //echo $rowz['vkid'] . '<br/>';
        }
        echo $count . '<br/>';
        $users_str = substr($users_str, 0, strlen($users_str)-1);
        //echo $users_str . '<br/>';
        flush();
        // Делаем запрос к VK API
        $usdata = array(
            'user_ids'  => ''. $users_str . '',
            'fields'    => 'sex, bdate, city, country, can_write_private_message, last_seen',
            'name_case' => 'nom',
        );
        $vkxs = new VK\VK($vk_config['app_id'], $vk_config['api_secret'], $vk_config['access_token']);
        $userff_data = $vkxs->api('users.get', $usdata);
        var_dump($userff_data);
        $users_str = '';
        $sqlstr = '';
        echo count($users_data['response']) . '<br/>';
        flush();
        usleep(1000000);
        echo $i . '<br/>';
    }
    echo $total . ' ' . $ttl . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Не в тему: зачем вы в цикле собираете через запятую id, и потом отрезаете хвост, если у вас есть массив `$users_array`, который можно потом соединить через запятую:  `'user_ids' => implode("," , $users_array)`.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на косяк этого класса `VK\VK`. API не возвращает NULL - в случае ошибки там появляется свойство error. На всякий случай посмотрите [статус платформы](https://vk.com/dev/health) – вдруг ВК глючит, но вряд ли.